# Rails 5 API only app serving assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-api, webpack-isomorphic-tools

I am new to rails only as a backend. And I am planning to develop a react/redux/rails app.

My question is how do I at least render an index.html when browser requests come in so that I can mount my react component?

Or should I not to use rails only as an api in my case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a small project. I just followed [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/348-the-rails-api-gem?view=asciicast) and it works.